# Any way to show only error on codesniffer

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I want to see only **error** in **codesniffer**. Because file have too many **warning** and i have only correct the **errors**. Can any know how to to do that?

Comment: Why not fix the warnings? They're violating the defined set of coding standards for that project anyway.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ i have only advised to fix the errors because fixing warning may caused the functionality problem. that take too much time to fix.

Comment: In `CodeSniffer.conf`, is `show_warnings` set to `0`?

Comment: **CodeSniffer.conf.dist** added this but not working `<?php
 $phpCodeSnifferConfig = array (
  'default_standard' => 'MEQP1',
  'report_format' => 'summary',
  'show_warnings' => '0',
  'show_progress' => '1',
  'report_width' => '120',
)
?>`

Comment: If you don't want warnings, use the -n option : https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Usage#checking-files-and-folders

Comment: @GregSherwood thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks @GregSherwood following this [link](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Usage#checking-files-and-folders)

```
phpcs -n --standard=MEQP1 pathtofile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be.

```
phpcs -n --standard=Drupal --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,css,info,txt,md pathtofile
```

Replace **pathtofile** with the file or directory of your own.